# How do i pull variables into $username = $_GET['example'] from a url PHP

Tags: php

I have created a simple API service for my login page which posts data to my API using cURL and that works but in my API index I keep getting an error:

> undefined index username

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  $username = $_GET['username'];
  $password = $_GET['password'];
```

but when i hard code it into the url http://www.example.com/LoginApi/index.php?username=gerald&password=4321 it works

Comment: Most probably because $_GET is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: but when i hard code the variables into the url eg: http://www.example.com/LoginApi/index.php?username=gerald&password=4321 it works only when i'm running it via the REST client it returns the above error...

Comment: when you hard code it then the variable is populated

Comment: Show the code where you are calling it through Rest client

Comment: <?php         $apiUrl = LOGIN_URL;
        // Instantiate cURL object
        $runCurl = new cURL;
        $json = $runCurl->useCURL($userData, $apiUrl); and this goes through custom global curl class that i created... find it at https://github.com/Gerald34/Global-cURL